# Failing accessibility testing on Angular Mat Stepper

Tags: angular, accessibility, mat-stepper, axedevtools

So i have an angular application wherein im using mat-stepper. Im failing on my accessibility test regarding "Certain ARIA roles must contain particular children". See image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD2Yu.png)
I already did my research and found a closed ticket on github regarding it,
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26444
I already followed the instruction from the ticket and still no avail. Im just wandering if this is a bug that has not been solved or is there any work around for it.

I already tried researching about the problem and found a ticket from angular .https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26444